# How to compare time in sql query in two different formats(timestamp and java.util.date)?

Tags: java, jdbc

My sql query is generated by this java code :

```
public boolean generateFileForTable(java.util.Date lastSyncTime, NGMasterSyncData ngMasterSyncData, String fileName){
    StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer(200);
    query.append("Select ");
    query.append(ngMasterSyncData.getOperationModeCol());
    query.append(", ");
    query.append(ngMasterSyncData.getColumnList());
    query.append(" FROM ");
    query.append(ngMasterSyncData.getTableName());
    query.append(" WHERE ");
    query.append(ngMasterSyncData.getLastModifiedCol());
    query.append(" > ? ");
```

Where the value inside `getLastModifiedCol()` is in time stamp format `(07-JUN-12 11.30.00.000000000 PM)` and in the prepared statement for ? , we are converting the time recieved `(11-06-2012 11-59-50) in java .util.sql`
so basically i want to compare this time in timestamp format with the time i recieved in parameters `(last synn time -11-06-2012 11-59-50)`.

How should i proceed ? what should i put in my prepared statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well kapil, in java.sql.Date, you can compare only time-less dates, but as we see you have time in your date so you should use java.sql.Timestamp. The whole working solution is as follows.

```
  PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(query);

  prest.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(lastSyncTime.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Symply do this when inserting the value in the preparedStatement :

```
    ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(myDate.getTime()));
```